# Develop a similar to Microsoft's 5 star developer exam soft? (Quiz Engine)

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, frameworks

I have a project where I have to make an asp.net application similar to the Microsoft's 5 star developer exam. I mean there should be many questions with many options, some questions have just one correct answer and some others have many correct answers. And time controlled. Obviously a DB where to store everything and keep historical data.

Is there something already made on FWK 3.5 C# free out there? Is there any framework already made for this, I need to speed up the project time so if there is something already made that I can use for my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously are working in the MS frame so have you looked at Semblio? It a new(ish) MS product for building interactive course material. It appears to integrate with .net etc. Comes as an SDK with prebuilt templates etc.
[semblio](http://www.microsoft.com/learningspace/semblio/HowItWorks.aspx)

Comment: Thank you PurplePilot, I will take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A while ago (when .NET 2.0 was new) the ASP.NET team made a few sample videos on building a quiz engine. I believe that you can download the source code from [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-01.aspx). From memory the code was a little basic bit it might help speed up your development.

Comment: Thank you Kane for your response. I already checked that but Im trying to find something more robust and elaborated.- Thanks :D